# how to save public api array data in database in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

i have create a api,to get the pincode related area details.When i enter pincode it shows area details of that pincode.but sometime that pincode and its related details are not exist in my database ,so i need to call it by public api and also store that pincode and area details in my database.my collection having different field names such as state in my collection and state_name in public api json data,so how to do it?

code:

```
router.get('/pincode/:pincode',function(req, res) {
Pincode.find({pincode : req.params.pincode}, function(error, pincode ) {
    if(pincode == ''){
        var request = require('request');
         console.log();
        res.statusCode = 302;           
            request('http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/'+req.params.pincode, function (error, res, body) {

            if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                var pincodeData = new Pincode({
                    pincode:req.params.pincode,
                    body:body.PostOffice 

                });

                pincodeData.save(function (err,results) {
                    if (err) {
                        return err;
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(body);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    res.json(pincode); 
});
```

});

Comment: Please indent and format your code before posting, hard to follow this way

Comment: i am to able to store only pincode,also i want to store array response data using this code,how to do it?

Comment: why areyou passing req.body along with pincode in request call? remove that and body has a filed postOffice, try adding that in database

Comment: i also want to store pincode which i pass with api.then want to store data which is get by passing pincode public api .{"Message":"Number of Post office(s) found: 21","Status":"Success","PostOffice":
[{"Name":"Andora","Description":"","BranchType":"Branch Post Office","DeliverySt
atus":"Delivery","Taluk":"Kallam","Circle":"Kallam","District":"Osmanabad","Divi
sion":"Osmanabad","Region":"Aurangabad","State":"Maharashtra","Country":"India"}

Comment: I want to store data of PostOffice array.

Comment: I have left an answer below, try that

Answer (score 0):

while creating the Pincode object use,

```
var pincodeData = new Pincode({
       pincode: req.params.pincode,
        body:body.PostOffice 
  });
```

this would pass in the array of post offices as well as the pincode you passed

Comment: when i use above code,store only pincode. and remaining data as a empty.

Comment: can you show me your mongoose schema, and remove req.body from request call, only req.param.pincode is required

Comment: var PincodeSchema = new Schema({
    pincode: {
    type: Number
  },
PostOffice:[{
  Name: {
    type: String
  },

  Description: {
    type: String
  },

  BranchType: {
    type: String
  },

  DeliveryStatus: {
    type: String
  },

  Taluk: {
    type: String   
  },
   Circle: {
    type: String   
  },
   District: {
    type: String   
  },
   Division: {
    type: String   
  },
   Region: {
    type: String   
  },
   State: {
    type: String   
  },
   Country: {
    type: String   
  }
   }]
});

Comment: by adding above code,i getting error: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the code but the approach should be correct.
For changing the field name, what I can think right now is changing the JSON object. You can check if you find something on [Mongoose Middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) that can be used in your case. But what I did should work as well.

```
var request = require('request');

router.get('/pincode/:pincode',function(req, res) {
    Pincode.find({pincode : req.params.pincode}, function(error, pincode ) {
        if(pincode.length){           
                request('http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/'+req.params.pincode, function (error, res, body) {

                    //For changing field name
                    body.postOffice.forEach(function(entry, index){
                        body.postOffice[index]["state"] = body.postOffice[index]["state_name"];
                      delete(body.postOffice[index]["state_name"]);
                    });
                    pincodeData.update({pincode:req.params.pincode},{$push:{"body":body.PostOffice}}, {new:true, upsert: true}, function(err, docs){
                        res.json(docs);
                    });
            });
        }
        else{
            res.json(pincode);    
        }

    });  
});
```